Does this scheme of the program kernel's operation affect the use and utilization of memory?
Of course, I know that Java programs take up a fair amount of memory and are reluctant to give it up, but I still want to understand whether this scheme for constructing the program's work (for a small program) is optimal, because in the Windows task manager it shows me that the corresponding Java process associated with this program takes up as much as half a gigabyte.
I assume (and nothing more, and you are the guru here) that what happens inside the while loop is recreated with each loop, and therefore should be utilized as the loop completes (as something unnecessary), but it seems that this is not happening.
I know that the garbage collector itself knows when and what to do, but I would like to understand - are my assumptions correct or will such a scheme (as I showed) not necessarily contribute to the economical use of memory?
// an approximate simplified diagram of how the program core works
while (true) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(timeToWaite);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    final WebDriver driver = ServerUtils.getWebDriver();
            
    try {
        // the biggest work using webdriver happens here
    } catch (Exception e) {...}
            
    driver.quit(); // closes all the browser windows and terminates the WebDriver session

    // clean the tails if any remain
    Thread brokerThread = new Thread(new ProcessFinisher());
    brokerThread.setDaemon(false);
    brokerThread.start();
    try {
        brokerThread.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
}



I assume (and nothing more, and you are the guru here) that what happens inside the while loop is recreated with each loop, and therefore should be utilized as the loop completes (as something unnecessary), but it seems that this is not happening.

The Java GC does not necessarily collect objects immediately upon their becoming unreachable.  It does not necessarily collect them at all if there is no memory pressure.

I know that the garbage collector itself knows when and what to do, but I would like to understand - are my assumptions correct or will such a scheme (as I showed) not necessarily contribute to the economical use of memory?

I think you're trying too hard. The point of GC is that you don't have to worry (too much) about managing memory, but that's just what you seem to be trying to do.  Cooperate with GC by avoiding holding references to objects that you no longer need.  There is not usually any point to clearing object references or shutting down services that you are soon going to re-create / restart.
When you say:

the corresponding Java process associated with this program takes up as much as half a gigabyte.

... you are right to distinguish between the Java process and the program running within.  As far as the OS is concerned, the JVM is the process it is managing.  That process may obtain more memory from the OS at startup than it actually needs to run your program.  Under some circumstances, it might also obtain additional memory from the OS instead of performing an expensive full GC.
If you're using the Oracle or OpenJDK JVM then it has command-line options controlling the initial (-Xms) and maximum (-Xmx) heap sizes.  You might be surprised by how much memory your program actually needs, but once you determine that, you can use these options, especially the latter, to prevent the JVM from using more memory than it needs.  Do note, however, that making the maximum too small will lead to OutOfMemoryErrors, and leaving too little head room is likely to cause performance problems.
